# Dragon Boss strategy?

Tags: cuphead

So I'm stuck in Cuphead at the dragon boss.  I can't say I can see any attack pattern he follows is he really just a random attack pattern? I've been using the charge cannon for him.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can get a read [here](https://www.polygon.com/cuphead-guide/2017/10/2/16391916/grim-matchstick-fiery-frolic)

Comment: Can you elaborate more?  I never found that bosses moves that crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a really tough time with this boss as well. Some tips that you might find helpful:

1. In the first phase, try to stay near the left edge of the screen until he sticks his tail up, this attack is much harder to deal with if it ends up in the middle. By staying on the left, you'll leave yourself more room on the right when it comes up. The ring attack will always travel towards where you were when the rings launched, and the meteor attack will start at a random spot (but travels in a regular pattern).
2. In the second phase, watch for the flames jumping from his tongue. Before they jump, they will grin and face the direction they're going to jump in. If you can get on the side they're not facing (behind them) before they jump, they won't hit you. I try to stay in the middle of the screen for this part, as it makes it easier to get on the other side of the flames before they jump.
3. In the third phase, try not to hit the flame projectiles, since they will split when you shoot them. I also try to stay either at the top or bottom of the screen for this phase, since this makes it easier to avoid the flamethrower attack (which is only in the middle).

Also, remember that avoiding damage is the highest priority. You should always try to face towards the boss so you can hit him, but making sure you avoid an attack is more important. This boss is certainly harder than most of the ones before him due to the cloud platforming during the fight, but the bosses in the second half of the game will continue to become even more difficult.

Comment: Interesting I didn't know that about the meteor strike I just assumed it was fixed. Thats the part thats been throwing me off. Thanks!

Comment: @Zissouu I find the smoke grenade's dash pretty useful for dodging through the meteors if they're giving you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Also remember to take advantage of different weapons! The lock-on shot allows you to just focus on dodging for the second phase, and the charge shot is great for doing decent damage to the third phase without hitting his projectiles.